# How can I create an endless array?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to create an array in Python, so I can access the last cell in it without defining how many cells there are in it.

Example:

```
from csv import reader

a = []
i = -1
with open("ccc.csv","r") as f:
    csv_reader = reader(f)
    for row in csv_reader:
        a[i] = row
        i = i-1
```

Here I'm trying to take the first row in the CSV file and put it in the last cell on the array, in order to put it in reverse order on another file.

In this case, I don't know how many rows are in the CSV file, so I can not set the cells in the array as the number of the rows in the file

I tried to use `f.append(row)`, but it inserts the values to the first cell of the array, and I want it to insert the values to the last cell of the array.

Comment: why don't you just reverse the array afterwards?

Comment: If you add something to an empty list, the "first cell" is the same as the "last cell".

Comment: And `append` *does* append a value to the end of a list. If you want to insert a value to the beginning of a list, use the `insert` method.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I tried to use a.append(row) and it returned to me the array in the same order as it is in the original file. Now when I tried to use a.insert(-1, row) it returned me the list in this order: 
[['y'], ['z'], ['x']]

(the original order is: [['x'], ['y'],['z']]
and when I'm using append it is also [['x'], ['y'],['z']])

Comment: You need `insert(0, row)`. But why not just reverse the list at the end?

Comment: @Tomerikoo
Right, I didn't think about this. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up, your current code is going to raise an index error on account of there being no elements, so `a[-1]` points to nothing at all.

The function you're looking for is [`list.insert`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) which it inherits from the generic `sequence` types. `list.insert` takes two arguments, the index to insert a value in and the value to be inserted.
To rewrite your current code for this, you'd end up with something like

```py
import dbf
from csv import reader

a = []
with open("ccc.csv", "r") as f:
    csv_reader = reader(f)
    for row in csv_reader:
        a.insert(0, row)
```

This would reverse the contents of the csv file, which you can then write to a new file or use as you need

Comment: Calling `a.insert(0, row)` on every iteration makes it O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

Read all the rows in the normal order, and then reverse the list:

```
from csv import reader

with open('ccc.csv') as f:
    a = list(reader(f))
    a.reverse()
```